# amcharts ForceDirectedTree nodes label color

Tags: colors, label, amcharts

I can't seem to find out how to change the color of the labels displayed on a ForceDirectedTree bubble.

In all the examples, labels are written in white.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found it :

```
   networkSeries.nodes.template.label.fill = am4core.color("#000000");
```